# Grouping json array In Oracle Query

Tags: sql, arrays, json, oracle, oracle12c

I have Oracle table:

```
CREATE TABLE jsonarray_test 
(id VARCHAR2(50) PRIMARY KEY, 
json_array_str VARCHAR2(256), 
group_name VARCHAR2(50));
```

Data

```
INSERT ALL 
INTO jsonarray_test (id, group_name, json_array_str) values ('af1470c6-4883-454a-9cec-10cdd99c4446', 'sales', '["foo", "bar"]')
INTO jsonarray_test (id, group_name, json_array_str) values ('f310a5e0-b881-42d0-a4af-b6d1e9064676', 'sales', '["foo1", "bar"]')
INTO jsonarray_test (id, group_name, json_array_str) values ('688effbb-b665-4c58-b42a-be073823ec27', 'engineering', '["foo", "bar1"]')
SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Does Oracle support queries that yield following output? -- deduplicate and group all into single JSON array

```
sales       ["foo", "foo1", "bar"]
engineering ["foo", "bar1"]
```

Version: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Oracle 12c onwards, you can use [`json_table()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_TABLE.html#GUID-3C8E63B5-0B94-4E86-A2D3-3D4831B67C62) to unnest the json arrays: from there on, you can then deduplicate the elements, and finally use [aggregate function `json_arrayagg()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAYAGG.html#GUID-6D56077D-78DE-4CC0-9498-225DDC42E054) to rebuild the arrays:

```
select 
    group_name, 
    json_arrayagg(val order by val) new_json_array_str
from (
    select group_name, val
    from 
        jsonarray_test j,
        json_table(j.json_array_str, '$[*]' columns(val varchar2(10) path '$')) t
    group by group_name, val
) x
group by group_name
```

Note that, for some reason that looks like a bug to me, you *do* need `group by` to properly eliminate the duplicates: `select distinct` does not seem to work (dups are still showing in the resulting arrays - at least in my db fiddle).

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=6f1b3d93e72f799bc8165ff62944f714)**:

```
GROUP_NAME  | NEW_JSON_ARRAY_STR  
:---------- | :-------------------
engineering | ["bar1","foo"]      
sales       | ["bar","foo","foo1"]
```